# jquery datatable sort by image

Tags: jquery, datatables

i have a jquery datatable which bind ok
its datasource has a column (status) if status =0 i show red image 
if 1 show image yellow if 2 show image green 
that all ok but i need to be able to sort that column (status column value)

```
     var table;var columnArrayToHide = [
3,4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,16,17, 18, 19, 20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
    ]; 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        BindDataTable();
    });
    function BindDataTable() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: 'Query.asmx/LoadCarGrid',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (data) {
                table = $('#table').DataTable({
               var myData = JSON.parse(data.d);
                myData.sort(function (a, b) {
                    if (a.carStatus < b.carStatus) return -1;
                    if (a.carStatus > b.carStatus) return 1;
                    return 0;
                });
                    "dom": '<"top"i>rt ',
                    "bInfo" : false,
                    "aaData": myData ,
                    "columns": [

                    {"data":null},
                     { "data": "CarName" }, { "data": null },
                     { "data": "CarGroups" }, { "data": "CarColor" }, { "data": "Departement" },
                      { "data": "CarModels" },

                { "data": "id" }, { "data": "CarTypeName" }, { "data": "CarStatus" }],
                    "columnDefs": [
                        {
                            "targets": columnArrayToHide,
                            "visible": false,
                            "searchable": true
                        },{
                            "targets": 0,

                            "data": null,
                            "defaultContent":
                                '   <input type="checkbox" class="Check"/>' 

                        }, {
                            "targets": 2,
                            "data": null,

                            render: function (data, type, row) {
                                switch (data.CarStatus) {
                                    case 2: return ' <img  class="img2"    src="Images/Green_mark.png" />'
                                        ; break;
                                    case 1: return  ' <img   class="img1"   src="Images/yellow_mark.png" />'; break;
                                    case 0: return  ' <img   class="img0"   src="Images/Red_mark.png" />'
                                        ; break;


                                }


                            }

                        }
                    ] 

    });

    },
    error: function (err) {
        //  
    }
    })
    }
```

Comment: I think this line  myData.sort(function (a, b) ...  should be myData= myData.sort(function (a, b) {

Comment: A `var` declaration and an `Array.sort` method inside an object literal...?

Comment: myData= myData.sort(function (a, b) {  did not work either

Comment: Sort Not Working

Answer (score 0):

sort your data as follows:

```
data = data.sort(function(a, b) 
{
    if( a.carStatus<b.carStatus) return -1;
    if( a.carStatus>b.carStatus) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: where to put that code which event or which function

Comment: What function is calling render? Where are you getting your data? Are you calling the plugin on a table? without seeing your code I wouldn't know.

Comment: i have posted the full function

Comment: try adding it as the first line inside of success: function (data) {

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: data.sort is not a function

Comment: I see your actual data is  "aaData": JSON.parse(data.d); so  success: function (data) { var myData=JSON.parse(data.d); myData.sort... and then set "aaData": myData

Comment: the statment run with no consol errors but it does not sort by the image column i have updated the code